# Mongoose - how to group by two different counts

Tags: mongoose, count, group-by, aggregate

I need query like this:

```
db.items.aggregate([
{
    $group: {
        _id: '$dataset_id',
        labeledCount: {WHERE labels.length>0}, // this line is problem
        totalCount: {$sum: 1}
    }
}])
```

Item object looks like this:

```
{
 _id: 1,
 labels: [...]
 ...
}
```

result should look like:

```
{_id: 1, labeledCount: 4, totalCount: 5},
{_id: 2, labeledCount: 0, totalCount: 4},
...
```

**EDIT**:
This is the closest I got to:

```
db.items.aggregate(
    [
        {
            $group : { 
                _id : "$dataset_id",
                "labeled" :  {
                    $sum : {
                        $cond : { if: { "$labels.0": { "$exists": true } }, then: 1, else: 0}
                    }
                },
                "total" : { $sum : 1 }
            }
        }
    ]
)
```

Now I am getting the error:

> "exception: dotted field names are only allowed at the top level",

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the answer:

```
db.items.aggregate(
    [
        {
            $group : { 
                _id : "$dataset_id",
                "labeled" :  {
                    $sum : {
                        $cond : { if: { $ne: [0, { $size: "$labels" }]}, then: 1, else: 0}
                    }
                },
                "total" : { $sum : 1 }
            }
        }
    ]
)
```

Explanation: 
`{ $size: "$labels" }` returns number of elements in `labels` array. 
`$ne: [0, { $size: "$labels" }]` checks if `labels` has 0 elements

**EDIT**: 
I have just deployed this to server and it throws following error:

> exception: the $cond operator requires an array of 3 operands

But locally it works. Will try to check if it's mongo version issue, otherwise I am not sure what could be the problem

Comment: This will work on 2.6 and higher versions of mongodb